# Why flags on comments which are of no use got declined?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags

I just flagged two comments which are not looking of any use.

- > [Just tried: Works fine in git bash on Windows too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit/2713363#comment15991591_2713363)

  I raised a flag as no longer needed. Because the only reason why someone posts an answer, is that his/her solution is working. So I think that there is no need to tell the answerer that the given solution is working.
- > [This is great! It basically gives you the file summary that Github shows at the top of a commit view. Thanks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit/11442967#comment19832994_11442967)

  Here also, I raised flag as no longer needed. Because comments for *Thanks* or *+1* should be avoided. So, 50% of the comment is not of any use.

  *It basically gives you the file summary that Github shows at the top of a commit view*. Now, talking about this, this really don't add any information to help understand the solution any better.

---

So, I'd good reasons for flagging these comments, but still my flags got declined.

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I declined these flags because I just really live for post-mortem Meta discussions about every single declined comment flag, because that is an extremely constructive use of everyone's time. Wait, no. That's not quite right. Let me try again…

I declined these flags because these two comments, as I saw it, actually do each contain a useful nugget of information.

- > [Just tried: Works fine in git bash on Windows too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit/2713363#comment15991591_2713363)

  The utility of this one is obvious: the comment tells the reader that the answer's solution works properly in Git Bash on Windows.

  Now, there are two conditions under which that piece of information would be worthless:

  1. It was called out explicitly in the answer (or the answer was speaking entirely about those conditions—like, the question was *about* Git Bash on Windows).
  2. That the statement is a truism.

  You can tell that #1 is not true in this case because of (A) the presence of the adverb "too" in the comment, and (B) by reading the question and answer.

  You know that #2 is not true if you've ever tried to run software like Git that was originally designed for *nix systems on Windows. There are inevitably some compatibility issues or things that just never work quite right.

  In sum, the statement that a *nix solution (which [the answer that comment was posted on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713363) explicitly says it is giving) works on Windows is not a pointless truism. It actually provides future readers with a potentially valuable nugget of information.

  Absent a compelling reason to delete this (like, an extremely noisy comment thread with 20+ comments), I selected to keep it.
- > [This is great! It basically gives you the file summary that Github shows at the top of a commit view. Thanks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit/11442967#comment19832994_11442967)

  Okay, this one doesn't start out great. Normally, a "This is great!" comment is a prime candidate for deletion. I deleted a zillion comments like that from your other flags on that same Q&A.

  But if you read the rest of it, see that it provides a description of what the solution in the answer actually does—a description that is *not* contained in [the current revision of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11442967/2). The answer just presents the magic instruction sequences. It doesn't say what they do, or what the output looks like.

  Knowing what the output looks like is something that I consider to be useful information, even though it might be only of relatively minor importance, because it saves you from having to try the answer, run the command, and *then* discover it isn't what you wanted.

  Furthermore, lots of people are familiar with GitHub, so this struck me as a potentially quite useful way of describing the command's output/results.

I'm not going to argue that these comments should be etched into gold and hung on the wall. But I'm also not going to pretend that their presence is causing any problems, or that there was a compelling reason to delete them.